Webpack 5 Error after Successful build! ( Uncaught Runtime Error Inpage.js )
I'm using webpack version 5 with:

@babel/core@7.24.4
@babel/preset-env@7.24.4
babel-loader@9.1.3
css-loader@7.1.1
html-webpack-plugin@5.6.0
mini-css-extract-plugin@2.9.0
sass-loader@14.2.1
sass@1.75.0
webpack-bundle-analyzer@4.10.2
webpack-cli@5.1.4
webpack-dev-server@5.0.4
webpack@5.91.0

The console leading me to inpage.js file that I don't have it in my source I assume it's webpack thing (I'm newbie) and the code that cause's error is:
setConnectionUrl() {
                return Nc(this, null, function*() {
                    const {nodes: C} = yield this.bm.emit(Mu.GET_NODE, Ve.solana);
                    this.provider.connection = D1(C[0].url)
                })
            }

The part that giving error cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') is D1(C[0].url
Console Error:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
    at U1.<anonymous> (inpage.js:28930:39845)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at ce (inpage.js:28930:37705)

I tried Updating all of the subpackages like loaders, babels, etc. But it was not helpful.
I put my github rep link down here so you can take a look at the source and config file yourself.
Clone: https://github.com/mhmdmsvi24/Front-End-Projects.git
It's my first project and it's in early stages and each time I reload this bug appears I can click on the X and the projects works just fine but It's on my nerve.
I do not have enough reputation to post images please clone the project and check it out!

It so happened that I ran into the same problem a couple of hours ago. However, I seem to have figured it out. In my case, this error was not thrown by my application, but by a third-party browser extension called Trust Wallet. I suspect that you might have the same issue. Just delete it, and the error will go away.
